# Python serial write doesn't work FIRST run

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I have 2 programs to test serial communication, an simple arduino program that echoes whatever is on the serial port and a python program that writes to the serial port and prints the reply.

I'm having an issue where whenever I upload the arduino program and try to run the python the first time after I uploaded, it would be stuck on `print ser.readline()` which I'm assuming means for some reason python is not writing to the serial port.  I would have to quit the python program and run it again to get it to get a reply from arduino.  The program would continue to work until I re-upload the arduino then once again python wouldn't work on first run.  Also if I open and close the serial monitor before I run the python program it will work the first run.  Does anyone know what is the issue?  This is on Ubuntu.

arduino

```
String str;

void setup() {                
// Turn the Serial Protocol ON
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
      str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');     // Read the serial input
      Serial.println(str);             // sends ascii code

  }
}
```

Python

```
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 115200)

for i in range(0,4):
    str = "test string\n"
    ser.write(str)
    print ser.readline()
```

Comment: What is the error when the python program "doesn't work"?

Comment: In general you would have to wait a few seconds after uploading the new software to the Arduino, before trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
time.sleep(1)
ser.setDTR(level=0)
time.sleep(1)
```

after opening the serial port and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely related to many Arduinos resetting when a new serial connection is made.

The solution is to either add a delay (about 2 seconds works) to the python program between the serial connection being created and the first data being sent or modifying the hardware to prevent a reset on serial connect.

Answer (score 1):

By default python Serial might be blocking by default try removing the timeout:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 115200,timeout=0)
```

additionally have a peek at the [serial.threaded in the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=serial#module-serial.threaded)